# How to fetch the association table columns using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have Three tables 1) student 2) game and 3)student_game. Here `studentid` is the primary key of student table and `gameid` is the primary key of the game table. The association table has four columns `1) uuid 2) studentid 3) gameid 4) gametype`.

I am using the spring data jpa, So my student entity class has relation as follows,

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "student_game", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studentid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gameid"))
private Set<Game> GameSet;
```

Game entity has the following relation,

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "student_game", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gameid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studentid"))
private Set<Student> studentSet;
```

In my business layer, I am able to fetch the set of game names for respective student by using the following logic,

```
Student s = studentRepository.findOne(1L);
Set<Game> games= dd.getGamesSet();
games.forEach(game-> System.out.println(game.getGameId() + " : " + game.getGameName()));
```

Now My question is,

I need to fetch the gameType column value from the association table (student_game) by passing input as student id.

How can I fetch the association column values?

Please suggest the best approach to fetch the association table column values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong:

1. you're mapping the same, bidirectional, ManyToMany association as two different OneToMany associations, but using the same join table. This can cause undefined behavior, since you might, in the same transaction remove a game from a player, and add the player to the game.
2. You can't use the student_game table as a join table: every time a game is added to a player (or vice-versa), since Hibernate doesn't know anything about the uuid and gametype columns, it won't insert anything into these two columns, and this is not what you want.

What you need todo is map the student_game table as another entity. Let's call it a Play. Then, a Play has a gameType, field, one User has multiple Plays; one Game has multiple Plays. And you may of course make these two OneToMany associations bidirectional.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Instead adding a new table, If I remove the UUID field and GameType fields in the association table and add the gameType column in the game table, Then my table relation make scene?

Comment: Then you can use a bidirectional ManyToMany association: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e5588